# How can I host my own SQL Server database with my computer?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I was creating a Log in system based on a simple key with C# and SQL Server.

Here is my code:

```
private void Checker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Joze\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");

    string query = "Select * from First Where [Key] = '" + KeyBox.Text.Trim() + "'";

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count ==- 1)
    {
        CorrectKey(); //external method
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Lisence Key");
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine but obviously it does not work on someones pc since the connection is made through my database which is located on my Documents folder.

My question is, how would it be possible to make the SQL connection in order to make it to work for everyone else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use cloud, for example azure

Comment: Install and maintain a database engine that supports remote connections (there are several options for SQL alone) on a machine that is accessibly via said clients. Or, use database hosting provided by someone else.

Comment: Or, perhaps better - use a "Web API" (ie., eg., etc.) and hide the database access directly: clients talk to server X (HTTP), server X talks to the database Y (which could be local only as the code currently has; although perhaps move the file..), and everyone is happy. It is _very uncommon_ to allow *arbitrary* clients to access a database directly.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have your SQL database hosted somewhere that the intended users can access.

Signing up for Azure is free, and you recieve credit when you sign up.  This credit can be used to develop for free, and estimate the monthly costs of hosting a database in Azure.  These costs are based on the amount of throughput. If you only have a handful of users, it is quite inexpensive.

[Create an Azure account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/)

In Azure Portal, you create a resource group and add the Azure SQL Database resource to it.

[Create a resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resource-groups-portal)
[Create an Azure SQL Database resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-quickstart?tabs=azure-portal)

After the Azure database is created, you are assigned a connection string that you can use to replace:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Joze\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");
```

Note: Connection strings should reside in your configuration file, and you should parameterize any values you pass to the WHERE clause of your SQL query.  Also, if you plan on having this project access and query multiple tables, consider using an ORM such as Entity Framework for data access.

[Getting Started with Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/get-started)